# remove spaces for specific link in sass?

Tags: css, sass

Is it possible to select the links with the `no-space` class and remove the `padding-top` that is placed on the link?
I would need this space only for the links that don't have this class.
I don't know if it's possible just in SCSS.
I only need the `padding-top` on the first two `li`.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a>link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>link 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="nospace">link 3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="nospace">link 4</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here my SCSS:

```
ul li {

  padding-top: 32px;  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the padding is applied to the list item rather than the link itself, it may be better to apply the `nospace` class onto the `<li>` tag instead; then exclude it using the [:not()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) pseudo-class.

```css
ul > li:not(.nospace) {
  padding-top: 32px;  
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <a>link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>link 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nospace">
        <a>link 3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nospace">
        <a>link 4</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```